# Magento 2 - Cart Price Rule to Discount Subtotal While Keeping Tax

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, tax

I am trying to create a Cart Price Rule which allows for a 100% discount of the order's subtotal, while still including the subtotal's taxes to the customer.
Ex:

Customer is ordering $100 of goods (subtotal). $12 in tax is included on this order. We would like to only charge them the tax.

Is there a means to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `Apply Customer Tax` value to After Discount

Here is the guide in official docs
https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/tax/tax-settings-general.html#calculation-settings

[image]

Comment: Thank you - if we were to apply the tax after the discount, would that not mean that the discounted value of a 100% discounts = $0 in tax collected?